# How to Get the Onclick Images from the JavaScript to fall behind all the other images

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to get the splatter.png's to go behind all the gifs once they are clicked. I have tried using Z-Index but it doesn't seem to be working. Is it just set up wrong? Or is there an alternative way to set it up?

HTML

```
<head>

<title>Movement</title>

<style>

div.a {
width: 200px;
height:200px;
position:absolute;
background-image: url("ant.gif");
z-index: -1;
   }

</style>

<script src="jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="please-work.js"></script>


</head>

<body>

<div class="animatedDivs"></div>


</body>

</html>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
newDiv();
newDiv();
newDiv();
});

function newDiv() {
var $div = $("<div class='a'>");
$(".animatedDivs").append($div);
animateDiv();


$div.click(function(){
    $div.css('background-image','url(splatter.png)', ('z-index', -10));
    //$(this).data('clicked', true);
    var offset = $div.position();
    $div.stop(); 
    $div.position({left:(offset.left), right: (offset.right)});
    });


    function animateDiv() {
    var newq = makeNewPosition();
    var oldq = $div.offset();
    var speed = calcSpeed([oldq.top, oldq.left], newq);

    $div.animate({
        top: newq[0],
        left: newq[1]
    }, speed, function () {
        animateDiv();
    });


};


}

function makeNewPosition() {

// Get viewport dimensions (remove the dimension of the div)
var h = $(window).height() - 50;
var w = $(window).width() - 50;

var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);

return [nh, nw];

}

function calcSpeed(prev, next) {

var x = Math.abs(prev[1] - next[1]);
var y = Math.abs(prev[0] - next[0]);

var greatest = x > y ? x : y;

var speedModifier = .1;

var speed = Math.ceil(greatest / speedModifier);

return speed;

}
```

Comment: Have you tried using positive numbers for `z-index`?

Comment: @KevinJantzer yes I have and still yielded nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is where you assign your css method.

```
 $div.css('background-image','url(splatter.png)', ('z-index', -10));
```

jQuery.css() function can not have three arguments. You can either pass two arguments ( name, value ) or a json object ( name value pairs )

```
 $div.css('background-image', 'url(splatter.png)').css('z-index', -10);
```

or

```
$div.css({'background-image':'url(splatter.png)','z-index':-10});
```

Comment: Cool, I am glad it helped. Don't forget to mark it resolved. Ty!